# show cursor/caret at the beginning of input box

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-input

**PROBLEM**:
I have a html text input box with some text in it, when user click the input box, I would like to have the caret/cursor appear at the beginning of the input box.

I could move a caret by using setSelectionRange() function, but I don't like the effect 
that the caret shown at the end of the text input box then moved to the beginning.  I would like it to be at the beginning of the input upon shown.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/edh8mkht/1/

HTML

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myP" onmousedown="mouseDown()" value="Mozilla" />
</body>
```

JS

```
function mouseDown() {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.color = "green";
    document.getElementById("myP").setSelectionRange(0,0);
}
```

**QUESTION 1**:

I use mousedown event to move the caret, but it doesn't move the caret at all, the same thing happens if I use onfocus event.  Is that because the caret appears after this two events and making setSelectionRange has no effect?

**QUESTION** 2:

What's a good way to solve my problem by using javascript?  Note:  I cannot use placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Fiddle showing initial selection of text box](http://jsfiddle.net/edh8mkht/3/)

Requirements for this to work:

1. Have to be able to wrap your input in a `label` (or really any element which can accept a child node)
2. [Have to support `pointer-events` CSS property](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events)
3. You have to be able to move the firing event from the `input` to the `label`

**HTML**

```
<label for="myP" onclick="click();">
    <input type="text" id="myP" value="Mozilla" />
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input#myP {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function click() {
    var input = document.getElementById("myP");
    input.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    input.style.color = "green";
    input.setSelectionRange(0,0);
    console.log('click');
}
```

Important things to consider in this implementation:

- **It's essential that you protect your CSS selector with the element type.** In this case, it's `input#myP` as opposed to `#myP`.  Otherwise, the CSS will select both the `label` and the `input` in some browsers if the `for` attribute is specified.
- **You have to apply some style element to your label**, otherwise this simply won't work.
- **Your caret point will always be before the initial value when clicked.**  At least in Chrome.  That's part of the problem with your `setSelectionRange` call.  I'd have to do some research to figure out why that is.